# How to give UILabel a blinking effect in Collection View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uilabel, uianimation

```
- (__kindof UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    OfferCell *cell = (OfferCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.lOffer.alpha = 1;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
       cell.lOffer.alpha = 0;
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Now this gives my label (_lOffer) a blinking effect and this label is placed in a collection view cell.

This code works well on the run. But when I tap on the cell and move to next page and come back again, blinking effect doesn't happen. Where can I write that blinking code so that every time the label is blinking even if I move back and forth?

Comment: reload your collection view in viewwillappear while coming back

Comment: If comment works, added it an answer

Answer (score 1):

The answer i found was to reload the collection view in viewWillAppear.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

   [collectionView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: Dude someone else gave you the answer so make theirs correct

Answer (score 0):

Seems your datasource populating in **viewDidload**, try it in **viewwillappear** and reload your **collection** view. **viewwillappear** only will call while coming back.